# Incorrect string comparision happening with regular expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to use regular expression to validate my string data but regular expression does not seems to be working means
it is producing incorrect output.

I want to accept data like this :

```
Number+
Number.Number+
```

Here is data that i would like to be accepted :

```
2.5+ 
2.5
2+
2
```

Invalid data :

```
2..5
+2.
```

**Code :**

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string s = "2.5+";
           var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(^[0-9]{1,2}\.?[0-9]?\+?$)");
        }
}
```

Comment: Your regex looks a bit perl flavored. In .net you don't need `/[regex]/`. But youre regex works for me as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/KdS3if/1). I just added a $ to the end to prevent captuting valid parts at the begin of a line.

Comment: @Pretasoc Still I am getting false value with the Regex you have suggested.Regex.IsMatch is returning false with 2.5+ input

Comment: I cannot [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kGESqm) the error.

Comment: **Please write and post a short, complete program that we can cut-n-paste into Visual Studio that clearly demonstrates the problem.**

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry for posting partial code.I have updated the question :)

Comment: Your code seems to work for all the examples you have outlined.  Is there a particular instance that is not working as expected?

Comment: @Kami But I am getting false with the current code and with input 2.5+

Comment: Here, I'll post what I mean by an actual helpful reproducer. As you can see, in my reproducer it produces the expected outputs. Until you can describe how to reproduce the problem on someone else's machine, it's hard to know how to help you.

Comment: That said, your regular expression is still wrong. It accepts `000` and `2.` which I think is not your intention to accept, correct?

Comment: Well *we* are not getting `false` with the input `2.5+`, so either there is code that you are running that you are not showing us, or something is very broken on your machine and you're not telling us what it is.  Help us help you!

Comment: As Eric has pointed out, the code sample you have provided works for 2.5 and 2.5+ and returns false for the edge cases you have outlined.  Can you run the sample that Eric has created, or run your code in isolation - in a new solution? It may be that your actual code does something other than what the sample here does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, let me show you how to write a helpful reproducer:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string pattern = @"(^[0-9]{1,2}\.?[0-9]?\+?$)";
    // These should be true, and they are.
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("2.5+", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("2.5+", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("2+", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("2", pattern));
    // These should be false, and they are.
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("2..5", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("+2.", pattern));
    // These should be false, but are true because 
    // the pattern is wrong.
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("2.", pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("000", pattern));
  }
}
```

When I run that program I get exactly the behaviour that is expected, so no repro. If you are getting different results on your machine, something very strange indeed is going on; what results are you getting on your machine?

If the question is "how can I fix the bug in my regular expression so that it does not match `000` and `2.`?", you can do that with `(^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9])?\+?$)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and for your kind efforts towards helping me.Appreciated :).Yes indeed i did not wanted to accept 000 and 2. and I am so happy that finally I have got answer from you :)

Answer (score 1):

This Regex works for all the data you posted. If you allow more than one digit after the period, you must add the desired quantifier after the second `[0-9]`

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9])?\+?$");
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time.Appreciated :)